# I want to execute the parameterised query on an Oracle and SQL database using dapper

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, dapper

I want to write a query with a dynamic list of parameters. I want to execute the query on an oracle and SQL database using a dapper.
I know we can use "@" symbol for SQL server and ":" for Oracle, however is there any common way that I can use and it will work with the both environment(SQL and Oracle)?

Comment: database-neutral code is a myth.

Comment: Oracle is an SQL database so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean Oracle SQL and Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

No, basically. You'll need either two different queries, or some of your own regex/etc fixup.

(source: I wrote Dapper; the ADO.NET providers don't make this syntax option readily available in a cheap way)